# C++ workaround for templated polymorphism

Tags: c++, templates, reflection, type-conversion, polymorphism

```cpp
class Base{
public:
    template <typename T> T getValueAs()
    {
        //should return (T)this->getValue()
    }
    template <typename T> void setValueFrom(T val)
    {
        //should call this->setValue((Impl::value_type)val)
    }   
};

template<typename T> class Impl : public Base {
public:
    virtual void setValue(const T& val){ ... }
    virtual T getValue() const{ ... }
protected:
    T value;
};

//also some very speficic impl would be
class NumVal : public Base<int>{
};
```

I want to use it as :

```cpp
Impl<float> var;
var.setValue(42.0f);
Base* baseVar = (Base*)&var;

int convertedVal = baseVar->getValueAs<int>(); // should return (int)(42.0f)
```

I know we can't override the template member function, the restriction here is `Base` class does not know the exact value type of `Impl` class, is there an alternative to achieve something like that?

otherwise, I need to implement very specific conversion on base class to be overridden on descendant class like :

```cpp
class Base{
public:
   virtual std::string getString() = 0;
   virtual int getInt() = 0;
   virtual bool getBool() = 0;
};
```

so what i need is just `Base::get<T>()`

Comment: why is `Base` not a template with non template methods?

Comment: In CRTP pattern, your Base would be a template, and Impl would be `template<typename T> class Impl : public Base<Impl<T>>`. If you do this, you would be able to cast down in `Base`s `getValue()`. Although, it is not clear why you would want to do this, as `getValue` will always be overridden in derived class.

Comment: asked differently: Why use inheritance in the first place? Suppose you could override the template methods you wont be able to use them polymorphically, because they have different parameter / return types

Comment: Base can't be templated class, because I need to pass it around without "user" knowing the exact type the var holds, I simply want it like `void*`

Comment: maybe adding some intended use case to the quesiton would help to clarify. (your "I want to use as" does not need the base class)

Comment: use case would be like a registry of key-value pair, every var is named, then some module would just need the value in type of string, some other case only need is value is zero or other, for example std::cout << getNamedVar("test")->getValueAs<string>() << std::end

Comment: You've put yourself in an interesting position. If the derived classes do not have the same interface, should inheritance be used at all?

Comment: @user4581301 there is common interface that I didn't show in the code example just to simplify my problem, such as getName(), getLastSetTime(), etc...

Comment: is it possible to `getValueAs<Foo>` from an `Impl<Bar>` ? Edit: Yes, thats actually what the example shows.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number yes its possible but since the method `getValueAs<T>()` can't be overridden in `Impl` class so practically useless as of now

Comment: Are possible `T` be anything, or a limited subset of types (as for json)? (for the later, `std::variant` might help).

Comment: it could be anything, also we can define our own specific conversion method for any pair of T

Answer (score 2):

If you insist on the design, it can be implemented with a little help of `std::any`. Please note, solution below doesn't address this requirement:

> int convertedVal = baseVar->getValueAs<int>(); // should return
> (int)(42.0f)`

as currently I do not see a way to implement it.

```
class Base {
public:
    template <typename T> T getValueAs() const
    {
        return std::any_cast<T>(getValueImpl());    
    }
    
    virtual std::any getValueImpl() const = 0;
}

template<typename T> class Impl : public Base {
public:
   std::any getValueImpl() const override { return std::make_any(value); }
protected:
    T value;
}
```

This is type-safe at run-time - i.e. exception will be thrown if there is a mismatch in types. The drawback is that you will pay the price of double type-erasure (one in your `Base`, another one in `std::any` operations).

Comment: With a `dynamic_cast<Impl<T>>(this)`, there is only one type erasure.

Comment: @Jarod42 OP never said that `Impl<T>` is the only possible descendant of the base. It also is kinda awkward to `dynamic_cast` in the parent class method.

Comment: I tried this solution, but it does not solve my problem since mostly the type are incompatible like int to string, that's why somehow I need virtual override to works

Comment: @uray actually examples like `int` to `string` is what puzzles me a little. There is no magic that can make all kinds of combinations work.

Comment: @uray nowhere in your example you have `int` to `string` conversion. That can not be done in the current design. There are others, slightly different designs which could accomodate it, of course.

Comment: `T getValueAs()` with `T=String` is an extreme example, other one like `T=bool` for checking value != 0, i am thinking something like template specialization on descendant class, ofcourse if only we can override templated member function, the question is just is there any kind of trick to inherit and override templated member function, I was researched about c++ type erasure which come close to it

Comment: also I was thinking about visitor pattern, where the descendant class will write into target object of the requested `T`, target object can be any "adapter" class or any intermediary